# Why us Python code is evaluating to false when it is true?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

So I have used the below code and it keeps evaluating to False, but it True. Being a Python 2.7 noob, I am not sure why.

```
s = 'Z_15'

if s.startswith('Z_') & int(s[2:]) >= 15:
    new_format = True
else:
    new_format = False

print new_format
```

Also this variation:

```
s = 'Z_15'
sYr = int(s[2:])

if s.startswith('Z_') & sYr >= 15:
    new_format = True
else:
    new_format = False

print new_format
```

I have evaluated both parts of the conjunction and they evaluate to True, so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you purposefully using the bitwise operator `&` instead of the logical operator `and` ?

Comment: It might be clearer to write `new_format = s.startswith('Z_') and sYr >= 15`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise operator and it has [higher precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) than normal logical operators.  So, your expression is being parsed as:

```
if (s.startswith('Z_') & int(s[2:])) >= 15:
```

Which (in this case) is:

```
if (True & 15) >= 15:
```

*That* simplifies to:

```
if 1 >= 15:
```

which is an obviously false condition.

---

To fix the problem, use the `and` operator which does a logical `and` and has the correct precedence.

Answer (score 2):

You will get true as the answer when you use the logical and operator , not bitwise and operator

Modify your code to :

```
s = 'Z_15'

if s.startswith('Z_') and int(s[2:]) >= 15:
    new_format = True
else:
    new_format = False

print new_format
```

You can [read this article for more information](http://www.exelisvis.com/Company/PressRoom/Blogs/TabId/836/ArtMID/2928/ArticleID/14358/Logical-vs-Bitwise-Operators.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me. In fact, `s.startswith('Z_') and int(s[2:])` evaluates to `15`. But using `&` fails because we get `s.startswith("Z_") & int(s[2:])` evaluating to `1`.

Comment: @travelingbones precisely

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answers, you can do this

```
s = 'Z_15'
new_format = s.startswith('Z_') and int(s[2:]) >= 15
print new_format
```